# How to make input width size to animate while ajax query is chaning the size value

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

My JavaScript code:

```
function refresh_price() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"query.php?currency=<?=$currencycode;?>"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("value").attr("value", data).attr("size", data.length - 2);
    });
}

refresh_price();
setInterval(refresh_price, 5000);
```

HTML code:

```
<input id="value" type="text" value="..." size="1" readonly>
```

I tried to play with .addClass at javascript and the css class with transition: 2s; but it does not work. How to do it ? Basicly the width must animate everytime the ajax query is executing. My JavaScript code is doing 2 things, first is loading the value right after the page is opened with refresh_price() and second is looping with the setInterval(refresh_price, 5000). The animation must work for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution for your problem. if you would like this I suggest to Change your code like this.

Remember:
   You need to change "7.5" according to your font size.

```
<input id="value" type="text" value="..." size="1" readonly>

#value{   
   transition:width ease-in 500ms;
}

function refresh_price() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"query.php?currency=<?=$currencycode;?>"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("value").attr("value", data).attr("size", data.length - 2);
        $("#value").width((data.length * 7.5) );
    });
}

refresh_price();
setInterval(refresh_price, 5000);
```

This is the example. use this only get idea. use above code block. that is the solution which you want

```js
var  price=5000;
function refresh_price() { 
   var data="50000";
        $("#value").attr("value", price).attr("size", price.length - 2);
       $("#value").width((price.toString().length * 7.5) ); 
       
       if(price==1220703125000){
          price=5000;
       }else{
         price *= 5;    
       }
}

refresh_price();
setInterval(refresh_price, 5000);
```

```css
#value{   
   transition:width ease-in-out 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="value" type="text" value="..." size="1" readonly>
```

or use [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/BvXpvW)

Comment: Your code is actually expanding the width everytime the loop is executing which is not what I want.

Comment: In my example yes. But in your ajax it shoud work properly.

Comment: Don't use my example code. Use first code block. i changed as you want.

Comment: i changed my example check again